# How to tune tensorflow object detection output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I used Tensorflow object deteciton API following this [tutorial](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10) and trained it to predict custom images of three category. After 49K steps and with most loss < 0.05 I stopped and froze the model. When i try to detect the object from image. The model correctly detects the object but provides wrong class label also it only gives one label for all detected object. I have checked the test.Record and train.Record which correctly captures the bounding box coordinates and class/class_text. I tried debugging the prediction model and found the below scores: This output is class and score for that particular class for each proposal. It returns 300 proposal value but i edited just for the question.

> **Classes**:
>   [[2. 1. 3. 3. 2. 2. 1. 3. 2. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 1. 2. 2. 3.
>   2.
>     3. 2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 1. 2. 2. 3. 2. 2. 2.
>     2. 2. 1. 2. 2. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 2.
>     2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 2. 2. 2. 1.
>     2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 2. 2. 2. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 3. 2. 2.]]
>
> **Scores**
>     [[9.34299827e-01 9.87844169e-02 7.54007278e-03 3.31299962e-04
>     8.95422545e-06 8.40702705e-06 7.37192840e-06 2.25948543e-06
>     1.55862494e-06 1.32166167e-06 9.75570629e-07 5.88678745e-07
>     5.05015009e-07 4.21588567e-07 2.58588926e-07 2.14299249e-07
>     1.97753181e-07 1.18188609e-07 7.23913232e-08 6.49422844e-08
>     6.09321731e-08 5.54216335e-08 4.88208514e-08 4.80325468e-08
>     4.59127847e-08 4.42321024e-08 4.26271001e-08 3.75534768e-08]]

The correct class label was 3 which has very low score comparing to other 2 class. For this checkpoint it favors class 2, I tried retraining and stopped early then found the model skewed to different class. but all of them consist of exponential scores. When I tried using the tutorial dataset and record file it contained 6 classes. With early stop I got different normalized output and more importantly it was able to predict more than one class though the accuracy was poor the scores were normal.

> **Classes:**
>   [[1. 6. 6. 6. 1. 1. 1. 5. 6. 1. 6. 6. 1. 6. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 6. 6. 3. 3.
>   3.
>     3. 1. 5. 4. 3. 1. 3. 5. 1. 2. 2. 5. 1. 3. 5. 3. 6. 6. 6. 5. 3. 4. 1. 4.
>     1. 2. 3. 5. 6. 4. 3. 4. 3. 4. 3. 3. 1. 5. 4. 2. 6. 4. 3. 4. 3. 2. 2. 2.
>     1. 6. 2. 3. 3. 6. 2. 6. 2. 1. 1. 4. 4. 2. 3. 2. 4. 4. 3. 4. 2. 4. 4. 4.]]
>
> **Scores**
>   [[0.8057396  0.54363483 0.41639847 0.4116147  0.40117604 0.30583626
>     0.28162587 0.19588488 0.17949946 0.17705482 0.14739332 0.1368773
>     0.11625872 0.09852906 0.09733354 0.09538303 0.09463519 0.07830063
>     0.07063951 0.06350185 0.06187743 0.05515279 0.05392814 0.05084944
>     0.04962941 0.04584368 0.04244312 0.04015012 0.03859867 0.03793424
>     0.03495875 0.03406471 0.03277094 0.03216837 0.03211389 0.0311062
>     0.03045315 0.03031772 0.02878817 0.02855495 0.02775684 0.02764305
>     0.02756038 0.0258495  0.02555148 0.02552066 0.02524703 0.0251481
>     0.02503884 0.024954   0.02364612 0.02353399 0.02353344 0.02315213
>     0.0230271  0.02294012 0.02266986 0.02261656 0.02215081 0.02189769]]

I want to know why after so many steps and with very less value my model is performing very poorly and why it stuck to single class. How can I solve this issue ?

I am using 600 images as trianing and 72 as validation. I used labelIMG to crop the images.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's hard to say if 600 images is a sufficiently large dataset to train your model. It may be that the problem is harder and it requires more examples.

The scores themselves don't say much. It can be that the examples are just confusing or they are too different from the training data set (again pointing to you-need-more-examples).

You also don't show anything to suggest you are not over-fitting.

So consider some of the following:

- Consider switch to softmax for the prediction layer (makes the scores add up to 1.)
- Compute precision and recall per class and per data set. Compare the numbers between training set and validation set. If you see a big difference you are probably over-fitting or you need more examples.
- Compute a confusion matrix.
- Once you identified potential problematic points (recall low for class '3' for example), look at the examples. It may be something really obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is done by finetuning Faster RCNN model in tensorflow API which uses softmax.  The output is class and corresponding score for each proposal. IT was said that 100 images per class is sufficient and i used 200 per images. The issue is that the proposal is correct but the class prediction is wrong. Also i am using Training data just to test model and this output is unacceptable for training data.

Comment: @Unbanned Softmax: I find that hard to believe, because then the activations must add up to 1.; 7.45e-3 can't be the max out of 3 classes since 7.45e-3 * 3  is much smaller than 1. Something must be 
 wrong somewhere.

Comment: @Unbanned For the number of examples, it depends on how similar your task is compared to what was originally trained. If it's very similar then you are right. I don't know the details, so I can't say if it's enough or not.

Comment: Hmm Its the confidence, I am not exactly sure how it is calculated but I know the model uses softmax classifier. But i get your point and the second model which was stopped in very small steps have better output. I will try verifying the process to find the issue. thanks